# Regex lookbehind assertion issue

Tags: c#, .net, regex, lookbehind

this is my current regex:

```
(?<=[\$T|\s|\p{P}|\$%\$%])sampleString
```

I want to match all sampleString in my richtextBox

and some instance of sample string in my richtextBox is something like this :

```
$TsampleString
$%$%sampleString
```

The problem is that my regex matches this : TsampleString, $sampleString, %sampleString.

How can I fix this regex lookbehind assertion? thanks

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to match just the "sampleString".

Comment: Are you sure? Your Regex works fine from where I'm sitting

Comment: try typing TsampleString and the regex will match sampleString which I don't want to happen. the only characters need to be on the left side of sampleString is $T and $%$%, not T, $ and %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building the regex wrong.  You've got a character class (denoted by your square brackets) where you just want to list alternatives.  Try:

```
(?<=\$T|\s|\p{P}|\$%\$%)sampleString
```

Edit: Wait, I just tested.  Why are you using `\p{P}`?  That's punctuation.  `%` would be matched, among others.

Edit II:  " the only characters need to be on the left side of sampleString is $T and $%$%"

Ok, that makes it simpler:

```
(?<=\$T|\$%\$%)sampleString
```